# Texting without an assigned phone number

Tags: text

I have an iPhone 5C that is no longer connected to a service plan. I have given it to my son to use as an iPod-type device. I have an Android phone. Can he text me on my Android from the non-connected iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

He should be able to text you and anyone else. He needs to be on wifi (only) and use a 3rd-party texting app (for messages to Android) or Messages to another Apple device.

He will not be able to send any messages when not on wifi because he won't have any cell signal.

Comment: Thank you, but when I go to add the messaging app, it's asking for a phone number associated with the iPhone and we don't have that (the line was transferred to another phone type). Should I just get a free google number? Is that even possible?

Comment: You shouldn't have to add any messaging app, it should already be installed on the iPhone.  What version of iOS are you using (`Settings -> General -> About` then scroll to `Version`).  There should already be an app named 'Messages' installed to use.

Comment: It says 10.0.2 (14A456). I see the messages app. It's an android we're trying to text.